# How to have multiple custom themes in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, themes, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

My current code is as follows:

```
@Composable
fun AppTheme(darkTheme: Boolean = false,
             content: @Composable() () -> Unit) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) DarkThemeColors else LightThemeColors
    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = MaterialTheme.typography,
        shapes = MaterialTheme.shapes,
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

which im calling in main activity like that:

```
    @Inject
    lateinit var application: WeatherApplication

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AppTheme(darkTheme = application.isDark.value) {
                WeatherApp(onToggleTheme = { application.toggleLightTheme()} )
            }
```

toggle light theme is basically this:
isDark.value = !isDark.value

and then im calling onClick in another screen like that:

```
@Composable
fun SettingsScreen(onToggleTheme: () -> Unit)
IconButton(onClick = onToggleTheme)
```

this accomplishes the dark and light theme, now what if I wanted to have more themes, so something like this perhaps?

```
@Composable
fun AppTheme(currentTheme: String,
             content: @Composable() () -> Unit) {
    val colors = when (currentTheme) {
        "Pink" -> PinkThemeColors
        "Light" -> LightThemeColors
        "Red" -> RedThemeColors
        "Rainbow" -> RainbowTheme
        else -> LightThemeColors
    }
    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = MaterialTheme.typography,
        shapes = MaterialTheme.shapes,
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

how would I call it in an onClick button in another screen (one button for red, other for pink etc)?

I'm still a beginner so sorry for any confusion, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use Sealed class for currentTheme instead of string

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/daniyaljavaid/ThemingInCompose

Answer (score 0):

I am also a beginner, so please consider that I only give an answer to your main issue, and I don't consider things like if your code has good architecure or follows best practices (That's why I also use hardcoded Strings in my example, but you should avoid that. I just do so, because it makes easier for you to understand the solution.). I think that your main issue is not the question which you asked in the title, but the last one: "how would I call it in an onClick button in another screen (one button for red, other for pink etc)?". So, you have already achieved setting themes by toggling a Boolean variable with a callback, now what you want is to use a String variable to choose from more than two themes. If you want to pass a String value with a callback, you can do the following:

```
@Composable
fun SettingsScreen(onChooseTheme: (String) -> Unit) {
    IconButton(onClick = { onChooseTheme("Pink") })
    IconButton(onClick = { onChooseTheme("Light") })
    IconButton(onClick = { onChooseTheme("Red") })
    IconButton(onClick = { onChooseTheme("Rainbow") })
}
```

The source code for your WeatherApplication class is not provided, but based on your code, I think that's where you want to use this value passed up in the hierarchy, and that could be achieved like this:

```
SettingsScreen(
    onChooseTheme = { currentTheme = it }
)
```

`it` is the keyword for your String value, you can also rename it like this:

```
SettingsScreen(
    onChooseTheme = { chosenTheme ->
        currentTheme = chosenTheme }
)
```

Hope this helps, tell me if you encounter any issue.